# Samba server: Who used all of our storage yesterday?

Tags: linux, samba, shell

First day there is plenty of free storage space, next day someone used up all free space.

Is there an efficient way to find out which directory has an increased storage use?

I know how to find new files using `find . -mtime -2`, also how to get disk usage using `du`, but I need the combination of them both, eg find *big new files* or *heavily grown directories*

Answer (score 0):

The closest I think you can get is by using the `-size` parameter to find. Otherwise, you would need to have a report of usage from yesterday to compare the current state to.

Answer (score 0):

> big new files

You can use the `find` `-size` directive along wiht your `-mtime` to find these.

> heavily grown directories

This will be impossible without historical data to compare with.